# Number Generator using BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new in java programming. I', working on a homework which we have to use concurrency in our code. I've read a a lot of resources  but I don't know how to solve my problem. It has 5 parts if someone help me to understand the first part I'm sure that I can do the rest by myself. Could you please help me what to do?
 Here is the first part description:

There will be one thread whose job is to hand out numbers for testing. This thread will run the code in a class called NumberGenerator. This thread should use an instance of a class that implements the Java BlockingQueue interface as a method of storing the available numbers and sharing it with other threads that need it. You will only have one instance of this class running in a thread, and you cannot run it in the main thread.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * The NumberGenerator class is used to hand out numbers that will be checked by
 * other threads.
 */
public class NumberGenerator {
    /** The biggest number we plan to check */
    private final int biggestNumberToCheck;

    /**
     * A queue where we will place the numbers that we generate, which need to
     * be checked
     */
    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> candidateQueue;
    private final int smallesrNumberStart;

    // TODO: What other state do we need?

    /**
     * Create a new instance of the NumberGenerator class, which will hand out
     * numbers that need to be checked.
     * 
     * @param smallest
     *            the smallest number to check
     * @param biggest
     *            the biggest number to check
     * @param queue
     *            the queue that we will put numbers to check into
     */
    public NumberGenerator(int smallest, int biggest,
            BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        biggestNumberToCheck = biggest;
        candidateQueue = queue;
        smallesrNumberToStart = smallest;
    }

    // TODO: You can decide how you want to turn this into something runnable as
    // a thread.

}
```

Comment: I put the description of the first part , Its the number generator.

Comment: yes, I just saw your edit :)

Answer (score 0):

To create a thread you have two [options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html):

1. extend from Thread
2. implement Runnable

So, pick one. In either case, you must override/implement the `run` method which holds the code that will be run in the created thread.

IIUC, in this case the method will generate random numbers and put them in the queue.

Then, in the `main` method, there will be an instance of `NumberGenerator` class instantiated with an appropriate implementation of `BlockingQueue`, pick one, there are [several](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) of them.

Finally, call the `start` method of the `Thread` instance to begin the generation of numbers.

Comment: So I have to write the random number generator inside the run method then in the main method I have to call the start, am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I added the word random there. The instructions doesn't say anything about what number to produce. You could even put always the same number un the queue. And yes, in main call start to launch the thread

Comment: Thanks,
I just have one more question How can I use the candidateQueue (which actually I'm storing all the numbers in it) in another class?